# Render React ES6 to String for Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I've coded an React Application in ES6 style, all my Components are build like the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="testDiv">
                Hello Word
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Test;
```

This website is running via the default configuration via "npm start" at port 3000.

Furthermore I've an nodeJS application with an API via expressJS on port 8080. Now I want to create an single route to express where I can render the React application and deliver the HTML String back to the client. What's the best way to do this ? I'm new to React development, hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimalistic example how to render your Test component on an Express server:

```
import express from 'express';
import Test from './Test';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/server';

const app = express();

app.get('*', (req, res) => res.send(ReactDOM.renderToString(<Test />)));

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Now I get the following error:                      import Test from './Test';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word. I changed the imports to the following syntax: var Test = require('./Test');  But now I get this error: res.send(ReactDOM.renderToString(<Test />));
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: I was assuming you would have already set up transpilation of your JSX code with Babel and webpack, as most React projects do. If you want to render your React components on the server, you need to transpile your code, the same way you're probably already doing with your client code.

Comment: You may also want to upgrade your local version of Node to one that can handle ES6. And I've found that including 'use strict'; at the top of the file can help as well.

Comment: @clrux Upgrading to a Node version that can handle ES6 won't help, because ES6 doesn't include JSX